# Div won't be at top of page

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` on my website that won't be on the top, it's always a little bit below the top so I was looking for a way to make it be at the top without space between the `div` and the top, but I've had no luck yet.

Here is the CSS code I've tried so far:

```
.usertopbar {
    display: inline-block;
    background: url(images/counterbar_bg.jpg) repeat-x #111;
    height: 32px;
    bottom: 600px;
    width: 1100px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 16px #000;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks ok (though I tend to avoid explicitly setting a height on things at all costs). I suggest including [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) before your own CSS. It will reset several of the browser's defaults, which is what I believe is getting in your way here. It's also the default used in the Bootstrap and Foundation frameworks, so you can bet it's one of the best reset stylesheets out there.

Comment: Normalize.css is not needed to achieve what he wants with the code that is provided.

Comment: Sure it's not *needed*, but it's become an fairly accepted staple in the developer toolbox if you want better cross-browser functionality. Perhaps more to your point, the OP should know that each browser has its own default styles built-in that it wants to apply to html elements. A solution like normalize.css is designed to reset all these styles so that you have a cleaner, blank canvas to start working on.

Answer (score 1):

Set the margin and padding or your `<html>` and `<body>` to 0. To be specific, I think it is the margin of the `<body>` that does it, but make it a habit to explicitly set them all to 0 by default.

Comment: In addition to @Gendarme's answer you can take a look at those resets: http://cssreset.com/ and choose one which suits you best for your future projects. It will save you a lot of troubles :)

Comment: I agree with @NikiMihaylov, though I would specifically suggest [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) (it's the default used in the Bootstrap and Foundation frameworks).

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add a dot (or hash) to the element. Be sure to set the `margin` and `padding` of `html` & `body` to 0. See the answer and cleaned code below. If you want to have the div sticky at the top, add `position: fixed;` and `top: 0; left: 0;` to the snippet.

```css
html,body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.usertopbar {
    display: inline-block;
    background: url(images/counterbar_bg.jpg) repeat-x #111;
    height: 32px;
    width: 1100px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 16px #000;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="usertopbar"></div>
```